# Conjugate Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $H$ and $K$ are conjugates of a group $G$ with $a \in G$, where $aHa^-1= \{aha^{-1} : h \in H\}= K$.
>
> Prove that the set $A= \{a \in G : aHa^{-1}=H\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

For $a, b \in A$, $aHa^{-1} = H$ and $bHb^{-1}=H$. And, $(ab)H((ab)^{-1}) = abHb^{-1}a^{-1} = a(bHb^{-1})a^{-1} = aHa^{-1}$. So, $aHa^{-1}$ is contained within $G$, and $A$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Is the proof organized?

Comment: Your work is mostly correct, but your conclusion is off. You should be concluding that $(ab)H(ab)^{-1}= H$, because this implies that $ab\in A$. 

You also need to check that $A$ is non-empty and that $A$ is closed under inverses.

Comment: To check that $A$ is closed under inverses, would I say that $aHa^{-1}(aHa)^{-1}$ = $aHa^{-1}aHa^{-1}? So, $aHHa^{-1}$ means $H=H$, and $A$ is closed under inverses since $A$ is a subgroup of $H$?

Comment: You should check your formatting on the previous comment.

To show that $A$ is closed under inverses, we need to show that if $a\in A$, then $a^{-1}\in A$. But what does it mean to say that $a^{-1}\in A$? Well, it means that $a^{-1}$ has the property that $(a^{-1})H(a^{-1})^{-1}= H$.

Comment: I cannot edit it for some reason. Is my statement that $aHa^{-1} * (aHa)^{-1}$ = $aHa^{-1}aHa^{-1}$  = $aHHa^{-1}$ = $H$ correct? Then I presume $A$ is closed under inverses since $a^{-1}$ is in $A$.

Comment: Your statement is not correct, and doesn't really make sense. Remember that $aHa^{-1}$ is a _set_, so you can't manipulate it as you did in your comment.

Comment: Then can $a^{-1}$ = $b$ so that if $ab$ is in $A$, $aa^{-1}$ is also in $A$?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion not only about _how_ to prove what you're trying to prove, but also simply _what_ you're trying to prove in the first place. I'm going to move out of the comments and write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. We want to prove that the set $A=\{a\in G\,|\, aHa^{-1}=H\}$ is also a subgroup of $G$.

How do we show *any* subset of $G$ is a subgroup? There are three steps: the subset should be non-empty, the subset should be closed under products, and the subset should be closed under inverses. What do I mean by closure under products? I mean that if $a$ and $b$ are in the subset, then $ab$ is in the subset. What do I mean by closure under inverse? I mean that if $a$ is in the subset, then $a^{-1}$ is in the subset.

So now let's look at our particular subset $A$. We need to show three things: $A$ is not the empty set, $A$ is closed under products, and $A$ is closed under inverses. The important thing to remember throughout this is *what does it mean to be an element of $A$* ? An element $x\in G$ is an element of this subset $A$, by definition, if $xHx^{-1}=H$.

Now, to see that $A$ is not empty, notice that $eHe^{-1}=eHe=H$ where $e$ is the identity element in $G$. The equality on the line above exactly means that $e\in A$, so $A$ is not the empty set.

Next we show that $A$ is closed under products. Take $a, b\in A$. Then $aHa^{-1}=H$ and $bHb^{-1}=H$ as you noted in your original post. So $$(ab)H(ab)^{-1}=abHb^{-1}a^{-1}=a(bHb^{-1})a^{-1}=aHa^{-1}=H$$ and this means that $ab\in A$.

Lasty, we show that $A$ is closed under inverses. Take $a\in A$. Then $aHa^{-1}=H$. Multiplying this equation on the right by $a$ gives $aH=Ha$; multipling this equation on the left by $a^{-1}$ gives $H=a^{-1}Ha$. But recall that $a=(a^{-1})^{-1}$. So this last equation can be rewritten: $$H=a^{-1}H(a^{-1})^{-1}$$ which means that $a^{-1}\in A$.

Thus, $A$ is non-empty, closed under products, and closed under inverses. So we conclude that $A$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: So it is a matter of cycling $a^{-1}$ to form a 'inverse product' that is in the subgroup $H$ to show that the inverse is in $A$, since all of $H$ is in $A$. Thanks for the explanation.